# Hashtables and usage in Java

Tags: java, hashtable

What is Hashtables used for in Java? Further more please give examples of simple usage of Hashtables.

Comment: Well done everyone who replied - The OP now has a wide variety of answers to paste into his / her homework assignment.

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thank you guys, this site is AWESOME :D

Comment: Why does the homework comment keep coming up?  is there an FAQ here somewhere that says this site is not meant to be used for homework? This site is about knowledge: if the question is new then answer it, else point the person to the place where it has been answered.  

Oh, and the argument that we are not helping this person by answering is irrelevant. If the OP can't find the answers to such basic questions on his/her own. the real world will sort them out (e.g interviewing for a job).

Comment: Unbelievable - someone assumes it is homework and people start downvoting question and helpful answers. I have no sympathy or understanding for that. I had the same question regarding maps and collections in general when I started with Java and it was NOT homework.

Comment: @darren: It's not always about FAQs and rules. We are not just robots answering questions here. Having an alive and healthy community is also about "ethics". Just giving an answer to this question isn't helping anyone (I agree about pointing to resources [e.g. tutorials] though)...

Comment: @3lectrologos: I disagree. I think answering this question does help people.  A sophisticated knowledge base like SO has to be built up from the obvious and simple.  My problem with the question is that the OP obviously put no effort into searching for an answer that most certainly already exists.  This is happening a lot on SO.  That said, I disagree with people downvoting questions that look like homework.  SO is a resource just like any other forum, IRC or mailinglist.

Comment: stack overflow should implement deterrent negative badges like "rtfm" or "google it first" (i kidding here people).

Comment: @3lectrologos and others - I understand that you don't want to do other peoples homework - but everybody is free to skip those questions and leave it for others to provide answers. Nobody is forced to answer or even read a question on SO.

Comment: @darren: My problem was not the "easy" question, but that asking that kind of a question usually means that the one asking it hasn't searched at all and just wants an answer to copy blindly (I think we agree on that). Just for the record, I didn't downvote the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
map.put(1, "One");
map.put(2, "Two");
map.put(10, "Ten");
...

int n = ... // some number
String s = map.get(n);
if(s == null)
   System.out.println("No entry was found for " + n);
else
   System.out.println(n + " is " + s);
```

Note that there is standard Java class called Hashtable, however it recommended not to use it. Best practice is to create instance of HashMap (which is a standard implementation of a hash-table) and use it through its interface Map.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have a synchronized key value pairs, you will use hashtable. If you wonder why you need hashtable when there is hashmap, there are lot of resources available, [check here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=430247)

Answer (score 0):

Hash tables, in pretty much *any* language (not just Java), are used for mapping keys to values, with very good normal-case performance characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

It basically is used for like in any other language I know: To map keys to values.

You may e.g. think of a dictionary which maps keywords to definitions.